# This Distributed Cache host may cause cache reliability problems after Sharepoint servers removed

Tags: caching, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, distributed-cache

I recently removed 2 sharepoint servers from a 4 server farm and I get the following errors:

```
This Distributed Cache host may cause cache reliability;

More Cache hosts are running in this deployment than are registered with SharePoint.
```

Both errors are referring to the two removed servers.

The cache cluster shows only the 2 remaining servers as cache hosts.

I re-provisioned Distributed Cache, but I still get the error.

Also tried everything listed [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/03/19/sharepoint-2013-distributed-cache-appfabric-troubleshooting/).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here: http://alstechtips.blogspot.com/2015/02/sharepoint-2013-this-distributed-cache.html

First, get the ID of the Distributed Cache Service Instance (with PowerShell).
Make sure you edit the following command to add your WFE server name.

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.Server -Like "*<yourWFE>*"} | Select-Object TypeName, ID, Status | Sort-Object TypeName
```

Look for Distributed Cache in this listing, and copy its ID, then edit this command to include the ID:

```
(Get-SPServiceInstance <yourWFE-ID>).delete()
```

Then finally:

```
Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

Reanalysing the alert should show it disappear (fixed).

It's then up to you to decide whether you want to deploy another Distributed Cache Service Instance.

Answer (score 0):

@OutOfThisPlanet has the right idea, but his last line will remove the Distributed Cache from the entire farm, when odds are that you only have one or two offending servers.  Plus he's

- pulling all of the SharePoint services when you only need one, and
- he made it so you have to copy and paste the ID.

This is how I did it a little quicker:

```
$Service = Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.Server -Like "*<YourWFE>*"} | where typename -eq 'Distributed Cache' | Select-Object TypeName, ID, Status

(Get-SPServiceInstance $Service.ID).delete()
```

Answer (score -2):

I removed the errors from Sharepoint "Review problems and solutions" and ran the rules again. Errors did not show the second time.

Comment: This is not really a solution. Removing an alert does not remove the problem.

Comment: The issue did not appear afterwards.

Comment: I'd imagine that the ALERT didn't appear afterwards.

Comment: what do you mean? wouldn't the rule re-evaluate it again?